# Whats the difference between `git checkout -b branch` and `git checkout -b branch origin/branch`

Tags: git

As we know, I create a local `branch` branch I can use:

```
git checkout -b branch
```

But there is a `git checkout -b branch origin/branch`

I do't know whats the difference between them, who can tell me about it?
Does this command will create a remote `origin/branch`?

---

**EDIT**

I have three questions:

1.Whether the `git checkout -b branch origin/branch` create a branch in local repo?

2.Does `git checkout -b branch origin/branch` create a origin branch for remote repo?

3.Or is the `git checkout -b branch origin/branch` is create a branch from local repo master branch, and `git checkout -b branch` create a branch from current branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Whether the git checkout -b branch origin/branch create a branch in local repo?

Yes.

> 2.Does git checkout -b branch origin/branch create a origin branch for remote repo?

No, it creates a local branch which is identical to origin/branch (status of last pull)

> 3.Or is the git checkout -b branch origin/branch is create a branch from local repo master branch, and git checkout -b branch create a
>   branch from current branch?

The difference is the "what will be in the new branch". origin/branch refers to a local reference (can't be modified!) of the remote repo, branch is a local branch.

Have a look at the very good explanations in the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Comment: If I in the `dev` branch then `git checkout -b branch ` is a new branch from `dev` branch, alright? if i in the `master` branch I create a `branch` branch, the content is `master` branch content, alright?

Comment: @1243916142: Right

Comment: by the way: I think it's worth to read @poke answer. If you understand it, you really gain a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As [per the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt):

> **`git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]`**
>
> Specifying `-b` causes a new branch to be created as if [git-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) were called and then checked out. […]

So calling `git checkout -b new_branch` or `git checkout -b new_branch start_point` is equivalent to the following:

```
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch

# or

git branch new_branch <start_point>
git checkout foo
```

So let’s check [`git-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) on what happens with that start point:

> The command’s second form creates a new branch head named `<branchname>` which points to the current `HEAD`, or `<start-point>` if given.

Not specifying a start point means that the start point is `HEAD`, so `git branch new_branch` is equivalent to `git branch new_branch HEAD`.

So what does `git branch new_branch start_point` do? Create a new branch `new_branch` that points at the commit specified by `start_point`. If you don’t specify one, then that will be `HEAD` which is the currently checked out commit.

To sum this up: `git checkout -b branch` will create and check out a new branch `branch` that is at the exact same location you currently are at. `git checkout -b branch origin/branch` will create and check out a new branch `branch` that points at `origin/branch` which is the local copy of the remote branch `branch` on the `origin` remote.

Comment: Good explanation at a high level (+1). I think it would be worth to write a sentence about the special nature of `origin/branch` (which differs in its behavior from the local `branch`)